# Flagged user for continually posting bad questions but it was declined

Tags: discussion, question-quality, moderator-intervention

I flagged a high rep (~30k) user for repeatedly posting incredibly basic questions with plenty of dupes already on the site.

Examples (all deleted, sorry):

- [Calling a 'function' in
  java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972057/calling-a-function-in-java)
- [How to define a global variable in
  java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971485/how-to-define-a-global-variable-in-java)
- [How to format a string in
  java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50971219/how-to-format-a-string-in-java)

When I flagged, there were 5 poorly received questions posted in the space of 2 hours, 3 of which are above and I believe 2 Python ones which also had multiple downvotes (I guess they've also been deleted) that I couldn't find.

I flagged this because my intention was for a moderator to politely ask them to put more effort into their questions - that's all. I would never normally flag someone for a few bad questions but this was just a streak of absolute zero-effort posts. I expect every user to at least make a basic attempt to Google the answer, if nothing else.

The flag was declined with the reason:

> flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that
>   requires their intervention

Does this *not* require their intervention? Should I just accept it and keep downvoting and closing the duplicates?

Since I flagged, they've asked 20 question that I can see, totaling -13. Not a single one of them has a positive score. If you include the 3 deleted Java posts, that's -28 across 23 questions. Where's the tipping point, if this isn't it?

Comment: Afaik having high rep doesn't prevent you from getting a question ban, only recent activity gets evaluated. If this user continues on like this, the system will auto-intervene. I think that's why the mod thinks it doesn't require his intervention.

Comment: Given that the user answered the second question, this *could* have been a good-faith (if misguided) effort to create basic FAQs to close incoming questions as duplicate of.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I suppose the exact details of the algorithm are secret, though? I've never heard that it only applies to recent questions

Comment: @Michael They are indeed secret. I've heard 6 months named in some comments, but I don't have concrete evidence. I think just downvoting and closing is the right way to go (as long as the questions deserve it)

Comment: @Michael I think it is better to either remove the links (to make the question general and not point to a particular user), or to add screenshots for the deleted questions so users with less than 10k can see what are you talking about.

Comment: @yivi Okay. I'm hesitant to include screenshots because my intention is not to shame the user. I just want to know what I should have done, if not flag them. I'll include the question titles - it will be enough to give you a flavour of how bad they were.

Comment: @Erik von Asmuth: I've yet to see a 30k rep user blocked from asking questions tbh. Look at all the 10k rep users with thousands of old questions that never, *ever* get blocked despite continuing to ask the same bad questions after so many years.

Comment: @Michael If you don't want to shame just leave out the username from the screenshot. My magic (below 10k rep) 8-ball won't be able to find the user from a screenshot of the question(s) alone. (I think/hope)

Comment: Actually, André's suggestion is more effective to avoid shaming than just posting the links, since posting the links expose the user to >10k users anyway. (Although, to be fair, the question titles do give something away in this case).

Comment: @AndréKool @ yivi Honestly, I don't believe that the specific question content is important. I'm not going to include it because doing so would contradict that belief.

Comment: Then you might as well leave them out of the question entirely.

Comment: [Calling a 'function' in java](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IcDZArYio2wJ:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972057/calling-a-function-in-java+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=es&client=firefox-b). (Google cache)

Comment: You are contradicting yourself when you are saying that _"I don't believe that the specific question content is important."_ while linking to that same content in your question.

Comment: It seems like this user is branching out. Made all their rep in tags different to the ones they are asking in now, and are now asking very basic, broad, beginner, questions. Personally, I do not believe is mod-flag-worthy Just vote and flag accordingly.

Comment: @AndréKool I considered the links themselves, rather than the content, potentially useful if a mod decided to weigh in. I don't personally care if you can view the specific wording of the question or not.